# Counting characters for specific column across all lines in Linux/unix

Tags: linux

How can I count number of characters for specific column in tsv file , while  this column contains sentences and not a single string? ( I want to count for each line in the column).

for example : (in case of csv) counting number of characters for the second field/column:

Input:

```
ab, an apple  
ac, not juice   
ad, I like
```

Output:

```
ab, an apple , 7  
ac, not juice, 8  
ad, I like, 5
```

Comment: Space is also a character, so it's 8, 9 and 6 characters.

Comment: Hi space is not included ( I like =5 characters)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,length(gensub(/ /, "", "g", $2))}' sleiman.txt
```

I gave the file the name `sleiman.txt`.
What the awk does is:

- take `,` as an input field separator
- print the 1st and 2nd field unchanged
- strip the spaces out of the 2nd field, count the number of remaining characters, print it after the 2nd filed

So the output is then:

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,length(gensub(/ /, "", "g", $2))}' sleiman.txt
ab, an apple  ,7
ac, not juice   ,8
ad, I like  ,5
```

Comment: Thank you i got the output without the first column. (ab,ac,ad)

Comment: so replacing the comma with '\t' will work for tsv

Comment: Indeed ... maybe adjust your question or your data to reflect what you're actually dealing with. And feel free to accept the answer if it does what you're after ... @SleimanBisharat

Comment: Thank you I am dealing with Stack exchange data and need to count the number of characters for each question then to sort them in decreasing order. i have converted the csv to tsv to handles commas inside the questions/answers

Comment: awk -F, '{printf "%s,%s,%s\n",length(gensub(/ /, "", "g", $2)),$1,$2}' sleiman.txt    this worked with the column on the left.

Comment: @SleimanBisharat - as I said: I could only go by what was in your question - I can't know what you **really** want. If my answer helped you with your problem please feel free to accept it.

Comment: Heh. Merry Christmas to you, too. @SleimanBisharat